# Pagination metatags in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seo

I'm building a Rails app that heavily relies on SEO for customer acquisition.
My problem right now is that I have to add some meta tags like these:

```
<link rel="next" href="http://www.test.it/[URL]/3" />
<link rel="prev" href="http://www.test.it/[URL]/1" />
```

I've tried to look around for plugins or some kind of framework that could help me build this in an easy way, and in some respects standardize setting meta tags application-wide.

The ones I've tried are:

https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags

https://github.com/lassebunk/metamagic

None of these work, for some reasons I'm not able to understand how to do that, they all apparently support some kind of "link rel", but all specific to canonical and noindex.

Can someone suggest a library that is a little bit more generic, or at least supports search engines for pagination*?

- http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.it/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html